# Why does sbt-native-packager create a dangling image?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am using https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/index.html to create an image for docker container.

Running the command:

```
sbt docker:publishLocal
```

It creates an desired image for me:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sweetsoft/sapmock   latest              6721e5c95111        6 seconds ago       664MB
<none>              <none>              f51bdd5b68cb        12 seconds ago      703MB
openjdk             8                   bec43387959a        10 days ago         625MB
```

But why does it create a dangling image `<none>`?

The `build.sbt` file contains the following sbt-native-packager relevant statement:

```
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
enablePlugins(GitVersioning)
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080)

git.formattedShaVersion := git.gitHeadCommit.value map { sha =>
  s"$sha".substring(0, 7)
}

dockerUpdateLatest := true
dockerUsername := Some("sweetsoft")
dockerAlias := DockerAlias(None, dockerUsername.value, (packageName in Docker).value, git.gitDescribedVersion.value)
```

Comment: I guess it comes from your `enablePlugins(GitVersioning)` declaration. I have the same `built.sbt` file except with the git plugin and it is not creating that.